# Can I include a single ObjC class when compiling Swift code?

Tags: objective-c, swift

In my understanding, it will be possible to work with Obj-C classes from Swift and write test cases much more quickly, and see the results in a playground project.

Does *.playground support including just a single class, like an .m/.h pair? 
How does it work? Do I need to compile this class separately, or is it done automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, a pure playground allows to import only Cocoa framework (for now, at least).

If you want to import other modules, you need to create a playground file **inside an existing project**. That way, the underlying Swift code inside the playground can access your symbols.

Reference: [Does swift playground support UIKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009598/does-swift-playground-support-uikit)