# Is it possible to import third-party Objective-C code into a Swift playground?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

As suggested [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_75) I've been able to import my existing Objective-C code into a .swift file via the bridging header. As of yet I've been unable to do something similar with a swift playground - it does not seem to recognise the header in the same way that a swift file does.

Interestingly, and possibly suggestive of a negative to my question is that playgrounds do not appear to share the concept of target membership like .swift/.m

Anyone had any success with this or perhaps a different mechanism?

Comment: See also this dev forum post, which doesn't have any answers yet. https://devforums.apple.com/thread/227949?tstart=0

Comment: Cheers, will add my voice.

Comment: does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009598/does-swift-playground-support-uikit ??

Comment: Sadly no, that question appears to be confusion over OSX vs iOS playgrounds

Comment: @Jiaaro - System modules can be imported without issue, it's third-party code and modules that are the problem here.

Comment: As per the thread posted by @Matt, an apple dev suggested 'voting with the bug reporter' at bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: Rick has a definitive answer on the other, newer question, so I've pointed this one at that.

Answer (score 4):

See [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_75) for how to set up an Xcode project for importing Swift into Objective-C. Then create a playground *in that project* and the playground should be able to work with any of the ObjC classes in the project.

Comment: Unfortunately, see the response here: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/227949?tstart=0

Comment: Ah well, that's what I get for parroting what I hear in the labs. :) [File bugs](http://bugreport.apple.com) and stay tuned, I guess.

Comment: @CameronLowellPalmer - It was to a now-obsolete discussion on Apple's old forums about how this wasn't quite possible yet. The duplicate question linked above has more recent and relevant information.