# Xcode 6 Playground using Parse framework?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, xcode6, swift-playground

I would like to use **Parse SDK/Framework** my playground file but I get an error if I import it. I can import the iOS frameworks like `UIKit`

I know there are similar posts to this ([How to I import 3rd party frameworks into Xcode Playground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046160/how-to-i-import-3rd-party-frameworks-into-xcode-playground)) 
but i could not make it work for my project.

Any help here is very very much appreciated... I am not a complete newbie but am not an expert So as many details (almost for dummies ;-)) as you can please...Many thanks.

Comment: Any luck with this ?  I was able to get Parse working, but not in the playground..

Comment: Based on some of the feedback in other threads this may have to do with 64 bit support in the Parse SDK.   Anyone have ideas on how to resolve this ?

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't get back earlier... Couldn't post comment from mobile for some reason... Anyway I got in touch with Apple Dev support and their answer was complete copy of the solution provided on Stackoverflow(see link in my post)... So I'm still stuck but I haven't spent much more effort on this afterwards Maybe the new Xcode and parse allow that...

Comment: Do you have the bridge header file? If you import a third party framework, you have to add the #import statement in the objc-swift bridge header file for it be accessible in your swift classes.

Comment: Has anyone had any luck with this? I revisit this topic every couple of months.

Answer (score 1):

To get Parse working in playground you will need to create an Xcode project and include the Parse framework. Then within that project you can add a playground and import frameworks and code written in that project. Hope this helps.

If you are curious I did it for a framework I created and created a Playground inside the projects workspace. In that I import Dollar which is a custom framework but I guess you could import Parse and it should work https://github.com/ankurp/Dollar.swift