# Using Alamofire within a Playground

Tags: swift, xcode6, swift-playground, alamofire

I'm new to iOS development and using Xcode and I'm having trouble getting Alamofire to work within a Playground. There's some functionality I'd like to test out for proof of concept but the library is not linked to the Playground and I've tried getting it to play nicely. I have Alamofire set up to work within an iOS (not in a Playground) project before the installation instructions in the Github Alamofire repo were recently updated.

Any suggestions on how to get Alamofire to import properly in the Playground?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to I import 3rd party frameworks into Xcode Playground?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046160/how-to-i-import-3rd-party-frameworks-into-xcode-playground)

Comment: Please see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882996/how-to-use-frameworks-imported-with-carthage-in-swift-playground

Answer (score 6):

Apple provides excellent step-by-step instruction to do so here: [Importing Custom Frameworks Into a Playground](http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.2/#/devc9b33111c)

Comment: Now moved to here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/Playground_Help/Chapters/ImportingaFrameworkIntoaPlayground.html

Comment: And now apparently moved to here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/Playground_Help/Chapters/ImportFramework.html

Comment: any idea where it now is? urls seem to all point to http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/ now :(

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I consider to be the simplest straight line path:

#### Download and build Alamofire:

```
brew install carthage
echo "github \"Alamofire/Alamofire\"" > Cartfile
carthage update
```

#### Configure the workspace with a playground file and Alamofire.

1. From the `Carthage/Build/{iOS / OSX}` directory, drag the Alamofire.framework file into your link library list: `{Project Name} -> {Target Name} -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries`
2. `Command-N (create file) -> {Platform} -> Source -> Playground`
3. If not already in a Workspace file, `File -> Save as Workspace`.  To be paranoid, I close the project / workspace and (re)open the workspace.
4. Click on the playground file created in #2, and add the import `import Alamofire`

Comment: From all I read so far this should be the right way. Doesn't work for me with Xcode 7b6 though. I even tried adding the `Alamofire.xcodeproj` to the workspace without success. The playground just wont find the framework.

Comment: Have you made sure the binary is being built with 7 - you have set xcode-select correctly?

Comment: I have also tried these steps without success using xcode 7 GM.  Any other ideas?  I had this working a couple beta versions ago.

Comment: @stigi, @AJEzk: Make sure you are pulling the right branch - double check with Alamofire, but it might be `github "Alamofire/Alamofire" "swift-2.0"`

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  I have a playground within a project that has the Alamofire.framework.  The project is okay...can see the framework.  But the member playground can not.   Furthermore, I would like to have a stand-alone playground accessing the framework without need of a host project.

Answer (score 0):

You can try moving library to

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/
```

Then you can import and use it right in your playground

Comment: I couldn't upvote more!! Thanks!, This was the only solution that really worked for me!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a playground within the project also like in [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@LogMaestro/adding-playgrounds-to-your-xcode-project-79d5ea0c7087)

### Steps

- If the project is not in a workspace, save as workspace
- Create new Playground, by adding to workspace level in the project pane
- Ensure your project has a framework target. If it doesn't Edit the scheme to add a new `Cocoa Touch Framework` target (it doesn't need to have unit tests)

  - Add the files that you want to use in the playground, to the new framework target
- Build the Framework by selecting the target in the build box at the top
- In the playground, import the Framework. If the classes you want to use are not public, you need to import like so: `@testable import ModuleFramework`