# How to use frameworks imported with carthage in swift playground

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground, carthage

i have a swift project with some frameworks added via carthage. Is it possible to use those frameworks in playground inside project and how to use it, because

```
import Argo
```

doesn't work :(

Answer (score 17):

This stopped working at some point. Sigh

What I do now is

- Create a macOS > Command Line Tool.
- Create a Cartfile with `github "ReactiveX/RxSwift"` and run `carthage update --platform iOS`
- Go to the command line tool target and add the frameworks from Carthage/Build/iOS in Linked frameworks and Libraries
- Add the playground files.

At this point I’m able to run the playground files.

‍♂️

---

A playground has access to external frameworks if it is part of a workspace that builds a target configured to access those frameworks.

If you want to add a playground to an existing carthage project, you only need to save the project as a workspace (File > Save as Workspace…), build the target, and you are done.

If you just want to distribute a playground with third party frameworks, you need to create a dummy workspace. Here is a step by step example for a playground with the [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift) framework:

1. **Create a new Xcode project** of type Cross-platform > Other > Empty. Name it RxPlayground. 
   This will create this structure RxPlayground/RxPlayground.xcodeproj and open a blank Xcode.
2. **Download RxSwift** with Carthage

   - Create a Cartfile with this line: `github "ReactiveX/RxSwift" "swift4.0"`
   - Run Carthage with `carthage update --platform iOS`.
3. **Add a playground** to the project.

   - Click File > New > Playground…
   - Choose the iOS > Blank template and name it Rx.playground
   - Right click the project node and choose “Add Files to RxPlayground”.
   - Select the Rx.playground and add it.
4. **Create a workspace**

   - Click File > Save as Workspace…
   - Save as Rx.xcworkspace
5. **Copy the frameworks** to the products directory.

   - Close the project and open the Rx.xcworkspace
   - Create a Cross-platform > Other > Aggregate. Name it RxAggregate
   - Create a New Run Script Phase with the following content:

```
    cp -rv "${SRCROOT}/Carthage/Build/iOS/" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}"
```

At this point, Xcode and the Finder look like this:

[image: xcode]

Note that Carthage/ and Cartfile.resolved appear when you run Carthage, Without them, your playground will be only a few Ks.

[image: Finder]

Lastly, build the project (⌘B). Now you can use the framework in your playground:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play
import RxSwift

_ = Observable<Void>.empty()
    .subscribe(onCompleted: {
        print("Completed")
    })
```

Sometimes the first time you build (⌘B) Xcode doesn’t notice the new framework (sigh). What I do is click on the target and back to a source file, or re-open the project. I don’t have an explanation why this happens.

Comment: Before you -1 for complexity, note that this a step by step from scratch, and it lets you use binary frameworks instead adding the Xcode project that builds the framework.

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you

Answer (score 5):

In order for the framework to work within a playground, the project that produces the framework must be included in the workspace for your project. So to make this work you need to follow these steps:

1. If your project is not inside a workspace, create a workspace for your project by choosing `File > Save As Workspace` in Xcode.
2. Drag the .xcodeproj file from the `Carthage/Checkouts` folder into your workspace.
3. Run the build action on your framework target.

Comment: huh? i need support for some framework in playground, but not in project :)

Comment: These are the steps you need to take to make it work in the playground. Whether you use the framework in your project is up to you.

Comment: I have a same problem.I did it.But not change.where should i create playground file?

Comment: The playground file should be in an xcode project which is in a workspace containing your framework xcode project as well.

Comment: Thank you!I understand. I could resolve by myself,maybe.

Comment: @Neils but in this case you do not have a project ALL your code is in the playground the framwork is external installed via carthage

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by copying the built frameworks to the Built Products Directory, where Playgrounds in the workspace also searches for frameworks.
Note: you also need to run lipo and strip away unused architectures from the FAT binaries.

See more here:
https://github.com/richardnees/CarthagePlaygrounds

Answer (score 3):

Based @Jano's great answer (thanks for that), I created a fully functional playground to interact with Carthage frameworks:

https://github.com/backslash-f/carthage-playground

I included the **Charts** framework as an example:

[image: Charts example]

I tested with latest Xcode.

"*Works on my machine.*"

Comment: I updated the solution for Xcode 10.1, you can find it here: https://github.com/darrarski/carthage-playground

Comment: I just merged your PR. Thanks for that, you rock @Darrarski.

Answer (score 0):

Found how to do this without converting to workspace and adding .xcodeproj file from the Carthage/Checkouts folder into your project.
This works if you have some framework target that contains all sources you want to use in playground. This framework must be in "Embedded frameworks" of your main target.

1. Add Carthage .framework to your project from Carthage/Build/IOS
2. Drag and drop it from your project tree into "Embedded
   frameworks" for your main target
3. Add Carthage .framework to your
   framework target as Optional(In target Membership)
4. Add **import
   "Your framework target"** into playground

That worked for me