# How to install Alamofire in PlayGround

Tags: alamofire

I have installed AlamoFire on Xcode 8.2 without any problems. I can import it when writing some code in a project, but I can't import it in a PlayGround. 
Can someone tell me how to make Alamofire available in a playground?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Alamofire within a Playground](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049169/using-alamofire-within-a-playground)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

[Using Alamofire within a Playground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049169/using-alamofire-within-a-playground)

https://medium.com/@royels/how-to-use-alamofire-and-swiftyjson-in-xcode-7-s-playground-ff8290b55716#.g8r1c8mme

http://unsure.org/swift-playgrounds-and-dependencies/

if you need more help, please also refer to https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=alamofire%20xcode%20playground

if that still isn't working, upload your relevant code and project files so we can take a look

-fluid