# Import Parse Framework To Playground

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, swift-playground

How can I add a 3rd party framework into Playground? I've created a playground in my project workspace(see attached picture) but using the `import` statement throws an error for anything that is not a standard iOS framework.
[image]

Comment: You need to use the Bridging Header because it's probably in Objective-C. Just put "#import <Parse/Parse.h>" into your Bridging file

Comment: I don't think that's it, in all the other files it imports fine as `import Parse`. This seems to be a playground specific import issue.

Comment: Oh I see, I just found this though which pretty much is your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24048331/3443689

Comment: I wish that worked. But it does not. I revisit this issue every couple of months trying to find a solution.

Comment: plus one for wanting this capability in Xcode!

Comment: somebody please start a bounty... This is good question, and all good questions must have a correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]In Xcode 7 this has finally become very easy! Open a playground and save it in your projects root directory. Add the import statement and bing, bang, boom, you're done.

I'm using XCode 7.2

Comment: Really? Can you add a snapshot where the files(playground) and framework are?

Comment: @tika added to the answer

Comment: Must be morte to this as I cannot import a 3rd party framework used in my workspace.