# Xcode playground 'no such module 'SQLite' ' how to add module to it?

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

hi it's my first time to post.
I'm now doing a tutorial on Xcode 8.2.1 playground using SQLite from below website:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/123579/sqlite-tutorial-swift

I downloaded a Xcode source containing a playground and a SQLite project, and i uploaded it to the following path.
https://github.com/TerryDon2017/My-SQLite.swift-master-tutorial.git

I have the **error** message below:

> Playground execution failed: error: SQLite.playground:1:8: error: no
>   such module 'SQLite' import SQLite
>          ^  thread #1: tid = 0x1cd7d, 0x00000001094e9360 com.apple.dt.Xcode.PlaygroundStub-macosx`executePlayground, queue =
>   'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1

**I was told to do 2 things:**

1.drag the SQLite.xcodeproj to the workspace

2.set the build dependency

i think I did 1 ok but for 2 i could not find anyway to set the dependency for the playground. could you please kindly help? thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to I import 3rd party frameworks into Xcode Playground?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046160/how-to-i-import-3rd-party-frameworks-into-xcode-playground)