# UI controls not getting recognized in Swift Playgrounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode6, swift-playground

I am trying to declare some `UI` controls in `Swift` `playground` but the `playground` is throwing a error as invalid object.

[image]

I think none of the `UIKit` elements are getting recognized. And I have tried creating a new project and adding the `playground` file but even this did not work out. The `xcode` version being used is 6.4.

I have already gone through these(links),

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009598/does-swift-playground-support-uikit) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069479/swift-playgrounds-with-uiimage)
but didn't really help me to solve this issue.

Can anyone help me out to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you have iOS playground ? If not On the right side of Xcode Change “Playground Settings -> Platform” from OS X to iOS

Comment: Yes i have tried all these possibilities and again i have tried changing the resource type from "Absolute" to "Relative to Playground" and other options too..