# Xcode 8.3.2 playground live view rendering doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-playground

This code worked perfectly in previous version of Xcode, but now it doesn't show anything. It is only showing activity indicator that says "Running project"

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let container = UIView()
container.frame.size = CGSize(width: 215.0, height: 215.0)

var view = UIView()
view.frame.size = CGSize(width: 185.0, height: 185.0)
view.center = container.center
view.layer.cornerRadius = view.frame.size.height/2
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

container.addSubview(view)

let scaleAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
scaleAnimation.fromValue = CGFloat(0.6)
scaleAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(1.15)
scaleAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:    kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
scaleAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

let opacityAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
opacityAnimation.fromValue = CGFloat(0.0)
opacityAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(0.1)
opacityAnimation.duration = 1
opacityAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
opacityAnimation.autoreverses = true;


let circleAnimations: CAAnimationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
circleAnimations.duration = 2
circleAnimations.repeatCount = HUGE;
circleAnimations.animations = [scaleAnimation, opacityAnimation];

view.layer .add(circleAnimations, forKey: "circleAnimations")

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = container
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

What is wrong with it ?

Comment: I have pasted code as is to Xcode 8.3.2 (8E2002) and it works just fine. Tested on macOS 10.12.4 (16E195)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to enable the assistant editor to see the results.

**View > Assistant Editor > Show Assistant Editor**

Also see here: 
[iOS Playground doesn't show UI preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33543460/ios-playground-doesnt-show-ui-preview)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes closing the playground and restarting Xcode resolves the problem

Comment: Restarting Xcode fixed the problem with the live view not rendering any content